# calling the deployment yaml through client go examples

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I am trying to call the update deployment through the client go for k8. But I am having hard time update the changes from deployment.yaml file
any code examples for an equivalent to kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml through the client-go APIs

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you show what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

> This example program demonstrates the fundamental operations for managing on [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/) resources, such as `Create`, `List`, `Update` and `Delete`.

Code for this is available [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/create-update-delete-deployment/main.go) and the whole documentation for [Go client for Kubernetes.](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go).

Or you can just write your own function to deploy the yaml as a parameter.

```
func cellDeploy(pathToFileName string) error {
    cmd := exec.Command("kubectl", "apply", "-f", pathToFileName)
    stdoutReader, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    stdoutScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdoutReader)
    go func() {
        for stdoutScanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Println(stdoutScanner.Text())
        }
    }()
    stderrReader, _ := cmd.StderrPipe()
    stderrScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stderrReader)
    go func() {
        for stderrScanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Println(stderrScanner.Text())
        }
    }()
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error : %v \n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %v \n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: i am aware of this approach.but i was looking for something reading the file and applying the changes through client-go api
and examples in the repo are  not for reading yaml files

Comment: I did that in python.but wanted to know  something in go 
i am looking for something like this in client-go
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/create_deployment.py#L28